# Equivalent of bottle.get() in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: python, asp.net-mvc, bottle

Using bottle we can `@bottle.get("/post/<permalink>")` to fire an action based on the url request. What would be the equivalent of that in ASP.NET MVC? Are there any attributes available to apply same behavior?

Comment: Im not into bottle and python, can you explain a bit more about `bottle.get`?

Comment: @Marthijn Bottle is a mvc web framework for Python and beneath the above mentioned line will be a method declared that will be executed only when defined url will be visited. Much like action for each controller in ASP.NET MVC. I am not into python either btw.

Comment: I think you mean the `ActionResult` then; in mvc if the `HomeController` contains a `public ActionResult Index() {}` the code will be executed when the page /home/index is visited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unknowingly I was referring to [Attribute Routing](http://attributerouting.net/) in ASP.NET MVC.